# Basic filtering of json entries fails in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to filter the data at:
https://loicbertrand.eu/accidentologie/json/accidentologie0_75013_75014_2017-2022.json
per type of `victime_type`.

I tried the following:

```
fetch(myRequest)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => filter(victime_type == "Vélo"))
.then((data) => process_per_gravite(data, carte))
.catch(console.error);
```

which led to the error `ReferenceError: filter is not defined`.

I assume the `filter` step is illy formed.

---

### Update

I have read the answers provided at [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes) and tried to modify my question accordingly, but still cannot find the proper way to filter my entries.

Comment: Please update your link to `json` file, its giving a 404 error.

Comment: `filter` is an array method. You have to call it with `data.filter(...)`. Also it takes a function as it's parameter, so the full expression would be `data.filter(victime_type => victime_type === "Vélo")`